# Rails is not rendering my application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just created a new rails app in Rails 3.1.1, and my application layout is not being rendered in the browser. The only thing that is rendered is the code that I put in the views (e.g. views/public/home.html.erb).

It's only rendering what is being piped through <%= yield %>. For instance, localhost:3000/public/home is on only displaying this:

```
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<h2>Here we go.</h2>

<a href="/#">Visit the login page</a>
```

Here's what's in my /layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="user_nav">
  <% if current_user %>

      <li>
        Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>.
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %>
      </li>
  <% else %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Log in", login_path %>
      </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>


  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash#{name}" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>

  <h1>test!</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Here are my routes as well:

```
 root :to => "public#home"
  match "/secret" => "public#secret"


  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
```

Here's what's in application_contoller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

end
```

Here's what's in public_controller.rb:

```
class PublicController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def home
  end

  def secret
  end
end
```

Here's what's in sessions_contoller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = login(params[:email], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
    if user
      redirect_back_or_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password was invalid"
      render :new
   end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged out"
  end
end
```

And here's what's in users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Also, I've started setting up Sorcery, and it renders the application at sessions/new, but not on my public#home action.

Comment: Read your question again and let me know if you don't say, "Huh?" :)  Please show your `views/layouts/application.html.erb` file.  Are you using the default layout or are you specifying it in each controller?

Comment: That was total gibberish. Sorry about that. I cleaned up the question and added my layouts/application.html.erb file. I'm attempting to use the default layout and haven't specified any layouts in any controller.

Comment: strange. is the layout is `/app/views/layout/application.html.erb'` and there is no `:layout => false` ? do your other normal view folders work?

Comment: Yep it's in /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and there is no :layout => false. The weird thing is that it's working at /sessions/new, which is the sorcery login page, but not on any of the other views.

Comment: Have u enabled cache or is there any  html file inside your public folder.Or try by including layout 'application' in your controller

Comment: Can you show the code for your controller? Also if you have a layout file with the same name as the controller it will use that by default

Comment: I have 404.html, 422.html, and 500.html files in my public folder, but these shouldn't be causing a problem. I tried adding layout 'application' to my application controller and that didn't work. But it shouldn't even need me to do that. In my config/environments/development.rb I have config.cache_classes = false

Comment: Just added all of my controllers to the original question. Those are the only ones I have at this point.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem myself and the problem is just a simple mistake.

Your controller PublicController is subclassing "ActionController::Base". Controllers other than your ApplicationController need to subclass from ApplicationController in order for their views to be rendered within the application.html.erb layout

If you change

```
PublicController < ActionController::Base
```

to

```
PublicController < ApplicationController
```

it should work.

Answer (score 13):

Ran into the same problem with one final wrinkle: I was overriding initialize in the subclassed controller. Make sure to call 'super' first thing:

```ruby
def initialize
    super
    @some_client = SomeClient.new
end
```